# Android Service or IntentService for app like whatsapp?

Tags: android, service, xamarin

I am developing a chat app. When a user connects to internet, the server pushes message notifications for him.

Should I use Service or IntentService for new message notifications? The service/intentservice must start on boot and never stop, even if we close the app.

Comment: Use Google Cloud Messaging.

Comment: I have developed custom notification system works on websites and iOS.
I don't want to use GCM.

Answer (score 3):

I expect if you are using your own push notification system, it's probably based on keeping a connection/socket open with your backend. You'll have to do that on a background thread because Android doesn't allow network operations on the main thread.

`IntentService` simply queues up start commands (issued via `context.startService()`) and executes them serially on a background thread; once that queue is exhausted it stops itself automatically. This is useful for performing relatively short-lived tasks off the main thread and in a context with less erratic lifecycle than an Activity. That doesn't sound like the best fit for something that must be always alive, so I think you should stick to a regular `Service` and manage your own worker thread to keep network operations in the background.